# Django-Mongodb : ConnectionError on Setting session variable

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-views

I was trying to implement custom user authentication and authorization application using django, mongodb.

While setting session variable I received connection error. I couldn't able to figure out why this is happening. Please help me to figure out this.

Setting.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mongoTest',
    'admin',
)
```

view.py

```
db = Connection().sms
...
def login(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    context_dict = {"form": form}

    if request.POST:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            p = db.user.find_one({
                "email": form.cleaned_data["email"],
                "password": form.cleaned_data["password"]
            })

            if p:
                request.session['member_id'] = p["_id"]

                context_dict["message"] = "Successfully Login"
                # request.session.set_test_cookie()
                return render(request, "admin/profile.html", context_dict)

            context_dict['message'] = "Your username and password didn't match."
            return render(request, "admin/login.html", context_dict)

    return render(request, "admin/login.html", context_dict)
   ...
```

eform.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Traceback

```
ConnectionError at /login/
You have not defined a default connection
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
You have not defined a default connection
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/connection.py in get_connection, line 93
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/virus/nlocate/project/test-project/djangoMongoTestApp',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/virus/nlocate/project/test-project/djangoMongoTestApp/admin/views.py in login
                request.session['member_id'] = p["_id"] ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in __setitem__
        self._session[key] = value ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in _get_session
                self._session_cache = self.load() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/django/sessions.py in load
        sess = super(SessionStore, self)._get_session(*args, **kwargs)
        if sess.get('_auth_user_id', None):
            sess['_auth_user_id'] = str(sess.get('_auth_user_id'))
        return sess
    def load(self):
        try:
            s = MongoSession.objects(session_key=self.session_key, ...
                                     expire_date__gt=datetime_now)[0]
            if MONGOENGINE_SESSION_DATA_ENCODE:
                return self.decode(force_unicode(s.session_data))
            else:
                return s.session_data
        except (IndexError, SuspiciousOperation):
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py in __get__
        queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection()) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/document.py in _get_collection
            db = cls._get_db() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/document.py in _get_db
        return get_db(cls._meta.get("db_alias", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME)) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/connection.py in get_db
        conn = get_connection(alias) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/connection.py in get_connection
            raise ConnectionError(msg) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Also please suggest me example project implemented custom user authentication and authorization using django, mongodb

Comment: Did you see the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818610/mongoengine-connectionerror-you-have-not-defined-a-default-connection)?

Comment: connection error arises when I added `request.session['member_id'] = p["_id"]` . I am able to insert value on db from view. So I hope this is different than the issue on above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you set `SESSION_ENGINE` variable on setting file. so When you request session, it tried to connect to mongodb and connection error arises.

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
```

When you comment above block (use default session engine) and run, connection error was resolved. Though I don't know advantave of default session engine to mongo session engine.