# Deployment of Django application using MongoDB on AWS

Tags: django, mongodb, amazon-web-services

How to define the settings of the django application for using the mongodb server running on the same instance as that of the django project. I tried it with `127.0.0.1`, `port 27017` (which I assume is the default port at which the mongodb server runs), in the settings of the django application. I then tried it with the IP address of the aws instance, but with no luck. It always gives me this error:

`ConnectionError: You have not defined a default connection`

My django project has the following mongo settings.

```
MONGO_SETTINGS = {
    'DB_NAME' : 'spotmentor',
    'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT' : 27017,
    'USERNAME' : '',
    'PASSWORD' : ''
}
```

Then I used the `mongoengine connect` to establish the connection.

I am importing the above `MONGO_SETTINGS` as `mongoset` and

```
from mongoengine import connect

connect(mongoset.get('DB_NAME'), host = mongoset.get('HOST'), port = mongoset.get('PORT'), username = mongoset.get('USERNAME'), password = mongoset.get('PASSWORD'))
```

I changed the value of the `HOST` key to the aws instance public IP and still I got the same `ConnectionError`.

I have also defined:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It gives you that error because you don't have a `DATABASES` setting defined. You need to read the django documentation.

Comment: I have defined
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}`

Comment: but I don't think mongoengine looks for the DATABASES settings key. Mongoengine connects to the database without using that key. If I skip that part I can directly use `mongoengine.connect` and still it works for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818610/mongoengine-connectionerror-you-have-not-defined-a-default-connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongoengine does not require any extra settings to connect to mongodb. The settings that you have provided must suffice.

I suggest you re-check your installation of mongodb.

Try `sudo apt-get remove mongodb` 
and `sudo apt-get install mongodb`

This should solve your problem.

Also, you need not define dummy db backend if you are not using sql-databases.